# inserting into a set which is part of map <int, set<string> >

Tags: c++, dictionary, set

I created a map containing a set as a value, but now I'm stuck on how to add the values into the set.

```
map <int, set<string> > myMap;
```

I tried something like this and it works fine, but it's useless for me, because I fill the set in the loop (so every set contains all values from the sets before, which is not what I what I'm looking for).

```
set <string> mySet;

while ( expression ) 
{
mySet.insert(str);
myMap.insert ( pair<int, set<string> > (myNumber, mySet) );
}
```

Comment: you meant `teachers` should be `mySet`? Show us the loop code might help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    #include <map>
    #include <set>
    #include <string>
    #include <iostream>

    int main(int argc,char** argv)
    {
        typedef std::map <int, std::set<std::string> > maptype;
        maptype myMap;


       myMap[rand()%100].insert("susan");
       myMap[rand()%100].insert("bob");
       myMap[rand()%100].insert("bill");

       for (maptype::iterator it = myMap.begin(); it != myMap.end(); ++it)
       {
           std::cout << it->first << ",";
           const std::set<std::string>& set = it->second;

           for (std::set<std::string>::iterator setit = set.begin();
                setit != set.end();
                ++setit)
           {
               std::cout << *setit << ",";
           }
           std::cout << std::endl;
       }
    }
```